# repeat pattern on curve with geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

is there a way to repeat the pattern along the curve in geometry node?
the red drawing is the ideal outcome.
here is the GN setup[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just put a Math Node set as fraction between the Spline Parameter and the Float curve[image]

Comment: thank you !!! fraction is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Mesh Line` node and `Intence on Point` and just this `curve` as `instances`.

The example is here.
[image]